# unique ID for every Device

Tags: android

Is there any ID kinda thing on an Android smartphone which is on every device unique? I want to store feedback, which the users sent me to my server, device specific. So the user can see if I fixed the bug they reported or if I implemented their idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get unique device id using::

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped very much!

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

**Device Id is unique for every Device**

```
    public String getDeviceUniqueID(){    
        String DeviceId = "";
        TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       //if your device contains sim slot
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
            DeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        }else{
        // if your device not having a sim slot 
            DeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
        }
        return DeviceId;
    }
```

Comment: Uh-ooo user is using a tablet that does not have a SIM slot.